# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'promise'

Tags: python

I get this error about a module called promise with most pip installs.

```
pip install promise     
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting promise
  Using cached promise-2.3.tar.gz (19 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

          version = __import__("promise").get_version()
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'promise'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I followed suggestions online to do:

```
pip install promise
```

and get the same result. I thought it might have something to do with the 'normal site-packages is not writable' but I haven't been able to fix that either (even after trying several suggestions online). I get the same error from the command line using:

```
python -m pip install promise
```

```
C:\Users\kshan>python --version
Python 3.9.9
```

I also updated pip:

```
C:\Users\kshan>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\kshan\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (23.0.1)
```

Comment: Please paste error messages as text not as images.

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable` is not necessarily the problem. I get that message too but I don't have any such issues.

Comment: @tadman 3.9.9 (updated in question)